# How to convert a style object into a compiled attribute value with Vue API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible using the Vue 2.x API to compile an object representing component styles into an attribute value suitable for the **style** DOM attribute? I am effectively looking for an imperative API analogous to the **v-bind:style** directive.

For example:

```js
const style = {
    fontSize: '14px',
    color: 'red'
}

const value = Vue.createStyle(style) // font-size: 14px; color: red
```

I am aware of the template compiler, scoped styles, the perils of user-provided style injection, the existence of v-bind, etc. I am looking to provide a style string to an element embedded in an inline frame, using a computed property.

I don't think it's relevant, but just in case it is, I am using a payment processor SDK that embeds payment information in an inline-frame to help minimize PCI scope requirements, and the SDK provides a function to set the inline style attribute of one or more fields embedded in the frame.

Comment: I am not sure if the style converter within Vue is public facing. You could do something hacky like `<div :style="myStyle" ref="dummy"></div>` and then on a watcher on myStyle use a `$nextTick` to get `$refs.dummy.style`. I would much rather write my own reducer in that case though.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
<button :style="cssVars">My button</button>
```

Then in your computed properties, you would write:

```
computed: {
    cssVars() {
      return {
        '--bg-color': this.bgColor,
        '--height': this.height + 'px'
      }
    }
  }
```

And lastly, use these variables in your styles:

```
<style scoped>
button {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  height: var(--height);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the style converter in Vue is public facing. While it is possible to do something hacky with `:style="myStyle"`, a watcher and a ref, I would just consider writing my own reducer like below. It should be a lot more stable than trying to use the internal Vue method that might change name in any release.

```js
const style = {
  fontSize: '14px',
  color: 'blue',
  padding: '12px',
  border: '1px dotted red',
  borderRadius: '6px',
  borderRadiusTopLeft: '0'
}

/**
 * @param Object style
 * @return String inline style string
 */
function styleConverter(style) {
  return Object.entries(style).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => {
      const convertedKey = key.replace(/[A-Z]/g, match => {
        return `-${match.toLowerCase()}`;
      });
      
      acc.push(`${convertedKey}: ${value}`);
      
      return acc;
    },
    []
  ).join('; ');
}

console.log(styleConverter(style));
```